# SSH connection error - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a Spark cluster on AWS using https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2.

I've generated a key and and login credentials, and I'm using this command:

```
./spark-ec2 --key-pair=octavianKey4 --identity-file=credentials3.csv --region=eu-west-1 --zone=eu-west-1c launch my-instance-name
```

However, I keep getting this:

```
Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: mec2-myHostNumber.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-myHostNumber.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com,myHostNumber' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I quit the console and then try to start the cluster again, I get this:

```
Setting up security groups...

Searching for existing cluster my-instance-name in region eu-west-1...
Found 1 master, 1 slave.
ERROR: There are already instances running in group my-instance-name-master or my-instance-name-slaves
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `--resume` to your `spark-ec2` command and try? Your slave may not have the key. `--resume` will make sure it is transferred to the slave.

[Running Spark on EC2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/ec2-scripts.html)

> If one of your launches fails due to e.g. not having the right
>   permissions on your private key file, you can run launch with the
>   --resume option to restart the setup process on an existing cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The command is incorrect. Key pair name should be the one you mention in AWS. Identity file is `.pem` file associated. You can't ssh into a machine with AWS credentials (your csv file is credentials).

`./spark-ec2 --key-pair=octavianKey4 --identity-file=octavianKey4.pem --region=eu-west-1 --zone=eu-west-1c launch my-instance-name`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know why I can't SSH with AWS credentials?    However, the error I had (the first one) persists.

Comment: You can't ssh with AWS credentials, because ssh doesn't work that way.

Ssh works like this:

You generate a key pair. You've private key. Public key is on the machine you want to enter.

On AWS, when you create an ec2 instance, you're asked to generate a key-pair. You're supposed to download that private key in your local machine and enter the path of private key, in place of "octavianKey4.pem"